# Google Analytics: Regex pattern

Tags: google-analytics

While working on Google Analytics,I have noticed the below regex pattern with multiple regex symbol .

^(sm|social network|social media)$

Could you please help me to understand what it means.

Thanks,
Aneesh

Answer (score 0):

Pattern,that using this symbols - **^** is describes start of the line, **$** - end of line. 
Symbols that written in the middle of this patterns describes matches with whole line.
**|** symbol equal to *OR*. 
At the end,whole line is matches *exactly* with *sm* or *social network* or *social media*

Answer (score 0):

this expression matches any of string "sm", "social network", "social media".
^ points to a start of string and $ to the end of the string so this expression wouldn't match social network**s**.
you can use regex101 to get an explanation of some heavy regexes: https://regex101.com/r/Ebup4n/1